# Issue Regarding MATLAB code for regression technique

Tags: matlab, statistics, signals, signal-processing, regression

I am working on steering wheel angle sensor that measures absolute angle of steering wheel. As steering angle sensors uses gears and several joints which is totally hardware related so in spite of calibration in start with the passage of time due to usage of mechanical parts and also due to some environmental and road conditions some errors occurs in the values of sensors (e.g. offset, phase change, flattening of signal, delay).

In short due to these errors in the measurements our aim gets distracted means If I am viewing velocity vs time curve so if in the original or calibrated sensor in short close to ideal condition sensor my velocity shows a peak in amplitude but due to error (hysteresis) in measured signal I am not getting peak in velocity curve or I am getting flattening of curve so it will affect my final task.

I have a tolerance let say 1.20 degree for hysteresis so that’s why I am having detailed idea about my signal and want to observe my signal if some changes means offset, delay, lowering has occurred in my signal or not. This will not only provide me an idea that whether to lessen the amount of sensors used for my task or made some changes in hardware of sensor to lessen the amount of hysteresis or do some other actions to reduce it.

What I have done uptill now in which uptill now I am not sure that whether I am right or wrong. I am getting some values for hysteresis but I have few questions regarding one of the technique I am using. If someone provides me an idea about it how to improve this technique or provide me a better approach then it will be nice and great guidance.

I have an ideal sensor signal (under ideal conditions which we want) and values from 1 sensor I have data of 6 different drives from car. I am explaining just 1 example of my first drive and its relation with my reference sensor data.

Given the data reference signal and sensor signal data of size 1x1626100 and 1 x 1626100 double for one reading from sensor but in all readings values from Ideal and measured signal w.r.t to time are same.

In short I want to find out the Hysteresis difference of sensor signal from measured signal.

In this method I have applied Regression lines Technique (On upper and lower values of difference signal).

I took difference of my signals (Ref – measured value of signal after applying my limitation on signal).

Applied regression technique by putting a threshold by myself above and below the difference signal means on upper values and on lower values separately and difference between upper and lower values regression lines is called as Hysteresis (Loss). Please have a look at figure 3 and 4 for clear view.

The Problem here with this technique is that I define the values for upper and lower regression line by myself after looking into data like up= 0.4, low= -0.4.

**Question:**

IS it possible that I could be able to write a program which decides the best line of fit by itself rather than giving a threshold?

Means is there any way that my code draw the best regression line for above values and best regression line for lower values and calculate Hysteresis.

I shall be really grateful to you all as I remained unable to find solution for this problem.

Thanks in anticipation.

```
         clear all
         clc
         drv(6)=load('20170420__142024.mat');
          t=drv(6).q_T0;
          ref=drv(6).Pos;
          lws_7=drv(6).SteeringWheelAngle;
          swav=drv(6).SteeringWhellRotSpd;
          vel=drv(6).KBI_angez_Geschw;

          sig_diff=ref-lws_7;
          mean_sig_diff = mean(sig_diff);
          offset_removed_sig_diff = detrend(sig_diff ,'constant' );
          offset_removed_mean_sig_diff = detrend(mean_sig_diff ,'constant');

           figure(1)
         ax11=subplot(321);
          histfit(sig_diff)
        dum=['Drive ' num2str(i) ': Differnce Signal With offset Removed for drive '];
        title(dum)
         hold on
         plot([mean_sig_diff  mean_sig_diff],[0 10000],'r')

         hold off

        ax12=subplot(322);
        histfit(offset_removed_sig_diff)
        dum=['Drive ' num2str(i) ': Differnce Signal With offset Removed'];
         title(dum)
         hold on
          plot([offset_removed_mean_sig_diff  offset_removed_mean_sig_diff],[0 10000],'r')
            hold off


           swvel_thres=20; 
           vehvel=60;  
           SAmax=90;

         t_lim=t(((lws_7<SAmax)&(lws_7>-SAmax)&(swav<swvel_thres)&(vel>vehvel)));

          sig_diff_lim = sig_diff((lws_7<SAmax)&(lws_7>-SAmax)&             (swav<swvel_thres)&(vel>vehvel));
           offset_rem_sig_diff_lim = detrend(sig_diff_lim,'constant');
            mean_sig_diff_lim = mean(sig_diff_lim);
            offsetmean_sig_diff_lim = detrend(mean_sig_diff_lim,'constant');


          figure(2)
         ax21=subplot(321);
          histfit(sig_diff_lim)
         dum=['Drive ' num2str(i) ': Limited Differnce Signal With offset Removed for drive '];
        title(dum)
          hold on
        plot([ mean_sig_diff_lim    mean_sig_diff_lim],[0 10000],'r')
        hold off

        ax22=subplot(322);
       histfit(offset_rem_sig_diff_lim )
        dum=['Drive ' num2str(i) ': Limited Differnce Signal With offset Removed'];
         title(dum)
        hold on
        plot([offsetmean_sig_diff_lim   offsetmean_sig_diff_lim],[0 10000],'r')
        hold off

      up=0.4;
      low=-up;
      stats_up =   regstats(offset_rem_sig_diff_lim((offset_rem_sig_diff_lim>up)),t_lim((offset_rem_sig_diff_lim>up)), 'linear', {'beta'}); %calculate linear regression for upper values
     intercept_up=stats_up.beta(1);
    slope_up=stats_up.beta(2);
    stats_low = regstats(offset_rem_sig_diff_lim((offset_rem_sig_diff_lim<low)),t_lim((offset_rem_sig_diff_lim<low)), 'linear', {'beta'}); %calculate linear regression for upper values
    intercept_low=stats_low.beta(1);
    slope_low=stats_low.beta(2);
    Hysteresis_LinReg = abs(intercept_low)+abs(intercept_up);

   figure(4)
    % ax31=subplot(321);
   plot(t_lim, offset_rem_sig_diff_lim ,t_lim,      t_lim*slope_up+intercept_up, t_lim ,t_lim*slope_low+intercept_low);grid
    legend('diff','reg up','reg low')
    title(' Limited Differnce Signal With offset Removed with regression lines for drive  ')

   figure(5)
  histfit(offset_rem_sig_diff_lim)
  dum=['Drive ' num2str(i) ':Offset Removed Limited Difference Signal  with Regression Lines for drive '];
    title(dum)

    hold on
   plot([ intercept_up   intercept_up],[0 12000],'r')
    hold off

    hold on
     plot([intercept_low   intercept_low],[0 12000],'r')
       hold off
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you need help obtaining the plot below the plot with the "triangles" or obtaining it is not a problem and you just want to automatically separate the points on the plot below it to fit two lines?

Comment: No this picture of triangle is uploaded just for example to understand. 
I have attached another picture I hope it will help for understanding my issue.
Actually in this figure there is a green and red line. Right now from my code I have mentioned a value 0.4 to draw these lines and perform calculations but I want to write an automatic code that will choose the lines for best fit by itself and draw these lines without manual dealing with code.

Comment: I tried calculating mean, standered deviation ,maxima but still not able to find out solution how it will be done. If u need some more clarification please ask question I will explain more .Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: The new added picture is plot of difference signal with regression lines

Comment: In code i have used up = 0.4 and low = -up to draw these lines but this is manual way I want to do it in automatic way that code detects best line and give me result for hysterisis.

Comment: I guess the last plot would be easier to analyze if you plotted only the values without connecting them with lines.

Comment: In the recently attached picture I have plotted ref-sensor signal means difference and then applied regression technique on it its simple i have tried to explain in code . I hope i remained able to make my situation clear to u because i will speak the truth with u i remained unable to find .some solution.

Comment: Also i this code we have to observe the difference plot manually and set the value for up and low by observing the plot but i want code to do it to find best line without human intervention for layman who do not know about code.

Comment: Ok, so your actual problem is isolating upper and lower points from the middle ones, right? Because if I understand the problem correctly the points in the middle are causing your approach with mean, standard deviation, extreme values etc. not to work?

Comment: perfect the middle points are error because we don't want those so we draw regression lines to separate upper values and lower values from middle ones especially for the points which we want means the best suited line for upper values and best suited line for lower values removing unnecessary points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a 1D version of the [k-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Standard_algorithm). k-means divides the data set into k sets (called clusters) - in your case **k = 3** (middle points, upper points, lower points) - in terms of how close they are to each other.

You can use the [kmeans()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) function provided by Matlab. It is a 2D version AFAIK, but you can reduce the dimensionality of your problem by setting the first (i.e. time) coordinate of each point to 0, leaving only the "y" (i.e. signal) values.

After k-means is done just select the points, whose mean value is the lowest and the highest, which would give you upper and lower points. You can get the means of each cluster by using this version of the function (see the linked docs):

```
[idx,C] = kmeans(___)
```

Matrix C will contain the means, and idx shows which point belongs to which set (cluster).

Then just fit lines to your chosen sets of points.

Comment: First of all really thanks to you for ur time and great reply but unfortunately This technique is just used to distinguish data by making clusters but what I want to ask is to find error between 2 signals.

Comment: Just small explanation:
What I am doing is I have a reference signal and I have sensor signal Data. I want to calculate how different my measured valued sensor signal data is from reference signal so I applied regression Technique on it means I defined Threshold by myself on this technique. This technique places a best fitted line for the data and difference between upper and lower line is error. But with K mean classification according to my knowledge it is only used to classify data by forming clusters means the data that is similar to each other in one cluster based on mean selected.

Comment: I am really sorry but I really appreciate ur time and effort and thankful to you and request u if you have some solution to my issue please let me know means regarding regression I request for ur expert opinion .Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: Frankly speaking may be I donot know how to find difference between 2 signals based on K mean clustering or please if i am wrong correct me in that case because I am not an expert in machine learning

Comment: From what you have described you may be able to calculate the error with k-means. K-means will let you filter out the middle points, because they will be in different cluster. The upper points will have their own cluster, and the lower points will also have their own, distinct cluster. You can fit the line to the cluster that contains only the upper points, then fit the line that contains only the lower points, and calculate the distance between the lines, which will give you the error you want.

Comment: It is an automatic approach since k-means should always cluster your data similarly if it looks similar to what you have shown, even if the mean and extreme values are totally different. This is just a little different way of finding the threshold automatically.

Comment: KjMag thanks a lot for ur help. It worked I got it .
Thanks a lot for ur efforts and time .Have a nice life .

Comment: That's great, glad to hear that. Do you mean that k-means worked for you? You may upvote and accept the answer if you think it has solved your problem.